# cmd+option replaces keyboard panel

Tags: macbook-pro, shortcut, macos

I want to use some application keyboard shortcuts.

Example on Sublime Text: <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>alt/opt</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> = Block comment current selection

I don't understand why my keyboard changes as soon as I press (command+option).

[image: Keyboard panel autochange]

You may notice on the image above, that panel has got replaced after command+option and so I'm unable to tab on /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about creating something in System Prefs/Keyboard/Shortcuts, you just type the key where the / is normally found.  What you are seeing is normal behavior in the Keyboard Viewer and does not affect the ability to make shortcuts using the unmodified keys.

Comment: When I press "cmd"+"alt/opt"+/, it does not function and brings Help->Search.

Comment: So you need to go to system prefs/keyboard/shortcuts/app shortcuts and change or uncheck the default short cut for Show Help Menu.